# Unable to retrieve backlog item details in Version one java SDK/API

Tags: java, agile, versionone

I am exploring (and integrating with my app) Version One SDK 15.1.1 for Java. I am  trying to retrieve all the backlog items details associated with a specific sprint under a specific project.

From each backlog item, I need to read title, ID, owner, Team. But with both SDK/API, I am able to find each asset's information separately without condition(i.e, finding story name from id).

How can I specify all the conditions together in order to do this (in either API/SDK) ? i.e Find sprint names using project name. Using selected Sprint, I'd like to retrieve stories and list each story's information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure if this is the answer to your question, but you can do both at the same time.  This says "give me a story that's in Sprint 1 assigned to Project 1".

```
/rest-1.v1/Data/Story?where=Timebox.Name="Sprint 1";Scope.Name="Project 1"&sel=ID,Number,Owners,Team
```

you can also replace "Story" with "PrimaryWorkitem" as well (if you want defect/story/test set)

Does that answer your question?